# AnacondaでインストールしたPython3がBracketsで認識されない

Tags: python, macos, python3, anaconda, adobe-brackets

BracketsでPython3を動かしたいと考えています。OSはMacOS Sirenaです。

Brackets Builder Extendedプラグインを導入しましたが、Anacondaで導入したPython3がBracketsでは認識されません。

ターミナル上でpythonと打つとpython3.6が起動します。which pythonと打ってもAnacondaのPythonのパスを指します。しかし、Bracketsでは何故かプリインストールであるpython2.7の方が実行されてしまいます。

それならばとAnacondaのPythonをpython3にリネームし、上記プラグインの設定を変えてBracketsで実行させると今度は/bin/sh:command not foundとなります（ターミナル上でpython3と打てばちゃんと起動します）。Anacondaの存在がまるっきり無視されてしまっているようです。

この手の情報がネット上に一切無いため質問させていただきました。ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Anacondaのpathが.bash_profile等で設定されているのが、Brackets側で認識されていない、ということはありませんか？
Bracketsでフルパスを指定できるなら指定してみると良いかもしれません。